# Computing the limiting distribution for order statistics

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, order-statistics

> Let $Y=(Y_1,Y_2,...,Y_n)$ be the vector of order statistics for a random sample from the Pareto distribution with pdf $f(x)=(1+x)^{-2}, x\ge 0.$ Compute the limiting distribution for rv's $nY_1$ and $Y_n/n$ as $n \to \infty$.

So I tried finding cdf first and I got $F(x)=\int_o^x(1+x)^{-2}= \frac {x}{x+1}.$ But 
I'm not sure if the integration is correct.

Comment: The integration is correct.

Comment: Thanks. So for $Y_n/n$ I got the limiting distribution $e^{-v^{-1}}$. But I'm not sure how to compute the limiting distribution for $nY_1$?

Comment: $P(nY_1>x)=P(Y_1>x/n)=(1-F(x/n))^n = \left(1-\frac{x/n}{x/n+1}\right)^n\to e^{-x}$.